# Google Earth Plugin eager re-render

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

I'm trying to animate points in a GE Plugin. The issue is that it seems to re-render itself every time I change an underlying geometry which ends up freezing the plugin.

```
var lineString = ge.createLineString(''),
    placemark  = ge.createPlacemark(''),
    coords     = lineString.getCoordinates(),
    features   = ge.getFeatures();

placemark.setGeometry(lineString);
features.appendChild(placemark);

myPoints.forEach(function(point) {
  // google earth re-renders on every one of these calls
  coords.pushLatLngAlt(point.lat, point.lng, 0);
});

// I want something explicit, like this, instead
placemark.redraw();
```

Instead of applying all the changes to the LineString coordinates and then calling a re-render method on the placemark, it re-renders every time.

The first idea I had was to do some type of double buffering. But I'm loading LOTS of points and I can't afford to double my memory usage.

Is there any work around for this?

**Edit:**

I tried removing the geometry, editing it, and then adding it back. The placemarks just flashed... :/

```
placemark.setGeometry(null);

myPoints.forEach(function(point) {
  coords.pushLatLngAlt(point.lat, point.lng, 0);
});

placemark.setGeometry(lineString);
```

**Edit:**

I did manage to get a significant speed increase by using [google.earth.executeBatch](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739)

```
google.earth.executeBatch(ge, function() {
  myPoints.forEach(function(point) {
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(point.lat, point.lng, 0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Minimize javascript/plugin interop by using [google.earth.executeBatch](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739)
- Use [frameend event](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/events) to time when you modify geometry.

  - A similar technique that is more of a hack, but possibly an alternative when frameend is not sufficient, is to [do geometry manipulation in the `fetchKml` callback](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-earth-browser-plugin/ACw8tLnCnTI).
- If you are concatenating line strings (or can pregenerate multiple line string segments), then try minimizing javascript/plugin interop by using [KmlCoordArray.push(KmlObjectBase coordOrList)](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_coord_array#adaf7bbed6380b16e22b20d9bd7384ad1) to conrather than pushing one at a time.

I see you edited your question to say you found the executeBatch function and that helped. You must be pushing a lot of points during every iteration to see the plugin hang.

Comment: Can you give an example to use KmlCoordArray.push(KmlObjectBase coordOrList)

Comment: Because there is no method of creating a standalone KmlCoordArray in the API, AFAIK, the KmlCoordArray.push(KmlCoordArray) is only useful when concatenating LineStrings. If you have multiple line strings (or can pregenerate multiple line strings), then you could do `lineString1.getCoordinates().push(lineString2.getCoordinates)`.  Not clear if that would be relevant to original OP's question. I've since come across another hack similar to using frameend that might be relevant, and I've updated my answer above.